# SQL Join and Count can't GROUP BY correctly?

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

So let's say I want to select the ID of all my blog posts and then a count of the comments associated with that blog post, how do I use GROUP BY or ORDER BY so that the returned list is in order of number of comments per post?

I have this query which returns the data but not in the order I want?  Changing the group by makes no difference:

```
SELECT p.ID, count(c.comment_ID) 
FROM wp_posts p, wp_comments c 
WHERE p.ID = c.comment_post_ID 
GROUP BY c.comment_post_ID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pre-SQL92 syntax, so I'll express it in a way that I'm familiar with:

```
SELECT c.comment_post_ID, COUNT(c.comment_ID)
FROM wp_comments c
GROUP BY c.comment_post_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(c.comment_ID) -- ASC or DESC
```

What database engine are you using?  In SQL Server, at least, there's no need for a join unless you're pulling more data from the posts table.  With a join:

```
SELECT p.ID, COUNT(c.comment_ID)
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_comments c ON c.comment_post_ID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY COUNT(c.comment_ID)
```

Comment: That was really just the easiest example for me to play with to get my head around join + count (it's mysql 5.x)

Comment: Understood. Expanded my answer with a join.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.ID, count(c.comment_ID) AS [count]
FROM wp_posts p, wp_comments c 
WHERE p.ID = c.comment_post_ID 
GROUP BY c.comment_post_ID;
ORDER BY [count] DESC
```

Comment: select p.ID, count(c.comment_ID) AS ccount from wp_posts p, wp_comments c where p.ID = c.comment_post_ID GROUP BY c.comment_ID ORDER BY ccount DESC;

^^ just returns all the counts as 1 (they are definitely not all 1)..

Answer (score 0):

probably there are no related data on the comments table, so please try grouping it by the post ID, and please learn JOIN statements, it is very helpful and produces better results

```
SELECT p.ID, count(c.comment_ID) 
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_comments c ON (p.ID = c.comment_post_ID)
GROUP BY p.ID
```

I also encountered that kind of situation in my SQL query journeys :)